Homology of torus with circles identified
This is a question about Hatcher 2-2 #9(c). It asks for the homology group of the quotient space of $S^1\times S^1$ obtained by identifying points in the circle $S^1 \times \{x_0\}$ that differ by $2\pi/m$ rotation and identifying points in the circle $\{x_0\}\times S^1$ that differ by $2\pi/n$ rotation.
All solutions I can find on internet, including this one, says $H_2(X) = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}^2$, but I really doubt it. I actually don't understand how the cell structure is given in the linked answer. I think we need $(m+n)$ 1-cells and $mn$ 2-cells with cellular boundary maps all being zero, so $H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}^{m+n}$ and $H_2(X) = \mathbb{Z}^{mn}$. This cell structure can be justified by giving complicated cell structure on torus before identifying, and we get the induced cell structure on quotient space.
Can anyone check this problem?

For a start, forget about $S^1 \times S^1$ and just think about what $S^1 / {{\sim}}$ is, where the relation is generated by $x \sim y$ if $x = e^{2 i \pi / m} x$ for a fixed $m$, then update your guess. Alternatively, if you know a few basic things about manifolds and group actions you can also prove directly that $X$ is just a torus again.

Oh, I think I misread the problem. I thought only $m$ horizontal and $n$ vertical circles were identified. English problem :(

I do not have access to the book, but for what it's worth my reading of the question is (like yours?) that we are identifying $m + n$ points (not $mn$ points), and do not obtain a torus as quotient.

@AndrewD.Hwang The book's available for free from the author's website. Reading the statement now, it's also totally unclear to me whether Hatcher wants to make these identifications only for some fixed $x_0$ or for all $x_0$. He simply doesn't say. My best guess now is that it's the former since the latter just yields the torus again.

@okaberintarou It seems your reading of the problem is the more interesting one, then. "English problem" indeed :^). If you want to further pursue this, I would recommend making explicit that $x_0$ is some given point in $S^1 \times S^1$. Also please disregard my first comment then.

There was some confusion about what the problem is actually asking, but after all $H_2(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, $H_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ is correct.
The following argument is essentially the same as the one in the answer you linked, but I tried to provide a slightly different perspective and a few more details.
To see this using cellular homology, note first of all that $S^1 / (z \sim e^{i 2\pi / m} z)$ is again homeomorphic to $S^1$ and that the projection map $q_m\colon S^1 \to S^1 / (z \sim e^{i 2\pi / m} z)$ induces multiplication by $m$ on $\pi_1({{-}})$ and therefore also on $H_1({{-}})$.
Let $S^1 \times S^1$ be equipped with its usual CW-structure with 0-cell $x_0$; in particular, let $a = S^1 \times \{x_0\}$ and $b = \{x_0\} \times S^1$ be the 1-cells.
Fixing some $m$ and $n$ and considering the quotient projection $p\colon S^1 \times S^1 \to X$, we can thus define a CW-structure on $X$ by declaring $p(x_0)$ to be the unique zero cell, then letting $\alpha := p(a)$ and $\beta := p(b)$ be the two 1-cells, and finally attaching a single 2-cell by taking the attaching map of the 2-cell in $S^1 \times S^1$ and composing with $p$.
The cellular chain complex then looks like this:
$$
    0 \to \mathbb{Z} \overset{\partial_2}{\to} \mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \oplus \mathbb{Z}[\beta] \overset{\partial_1}{\to} \mathbb{Z} \to 0
$$
As always $\partial_1 = 0$, so since the attaching map of the 2-cell in $S^1 \times S^1$ is of the form $a b a^{-1} b^{-1}$, the attaching map of the 2-cell in $X$ is of the form $p_*(a b a^{-1} b^{-1}) = \alpha^m \beta^n \alpha^{-m} \beta^{-n}$, using our observation about the induced maps of $q_m$ and $q_n$ above, so $\partial_2 = 0$ as well and the result follows.

As a sidenote, the linked answer also states

Otherwise you can just see, that the space $X$ is still a Torus [...]. So it is not surprising, that we've got the homology group of the Torus.

This is false. If $n > 1$ or $m > 1$, then $X$ is no longer locally Euclidean (think about what happens to a pair of Euclidean neighborhoods of two points being identifies).
